# Java Static Synchronized

Tags: java, multithreading

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How do synchronized static methods work in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578904/how-do-synchronized-static-methods-work-in-java)

Can someone make me understand the fundamental difference between the following two functions:

```
public static void synchronized f() {… }
```

and

```
public void synchronized f() {… }
```

Comment: The [second answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578904/how-do-synchronized-static-methods-work-in-java/582500#582500) in @Oli's link answers this question directly.

Answer (score 12):

In the case of

```
public void synchronized f(){...}
```

The synchronization is per instance of the of enclosing class. This means that multiple threads can call `f` on **different** instances of the class.

For

```
public static void synchronized f(){...}
```

Only one thread at a time can call that method, regardless of the number of instances of the enclosing class.

Technically, the monitor taken by `synchronized` in the first example is the of the object instance and the monitor take in the second example is that of the `Class` object.

Note that, if you have classes of the same name in different `ClassLoaders`, the **do not** share the same monitor, but this is a detail you're unlikely to encounter.

Comment: Is there a substitute for "synchronized" in Java, say we have same thread access restriction, without using "synchronized" keyword?

Comment: You can get the same semantics as `synchronized` by using one of the [`Lock`](http://download.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/concurrent/locks/Lock.html) implementations.

Answer (score 2):

In a "static synchnronized" method, the lock that is synchronized against is on the class itself; in a "synchornized" method, the lock is on the object.  Note that this means that a "static synchronzied" method will not be blocked by a running "synchronzied" method, and vice versa.  For more info, see: http://geekexplains.blogspot.com/2008/07/synchronization-of-static-and-instance.html

Answer (score 1):

I think:

`public void synchronized f() {… }` synchronizes on object itself (`this`)

`public static void synchronized f() {… }` synchronizes on `Class` instance of an object (`object.getClass()` or `SomeClass.getClass`)

I can be wrong

Comment: `this.getClass()` has no meaning if it's a static method.  I think you mean `SomeClass.class`.

Comment: @Mark Yes, thank you. I will edit my post. Am I correct anyway?

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the method f is in a class Foo.  The static version will lock on the the static method call at the class level (the object returned by getClass() or Foo.class).  The non static version will lock for particular instances of that class, so lets say:

```
Foo x = new Foo();
Foo y = new Foo();
// Locks method f of instance x, but NOT for y.
x.f();
```

In the static instance a call to f() will lock for both versions so only one method call to f would be executing at one time.

Comment: It doesn't "lock on the static method call", it locks on the `.class` object.