# How can class method access be safely controlled in a C++ mutli threaded program using boost?

Tags: java, c++, multithreading, boost

I want to translate some Java code into C++. One of the Java classes extends the Thread class and contains the following method:

```
 public static synchronized String createUniqueID() {
    //some code here
}
```

How can I synchronize (in the Java sense of the word) class methods in C++ using Boost?  I have read about using `boost::mutex` for synchronizing access to shared data, but I am not sure how to apply this to C++ class methods.

Comment: Do you know what `synchronized` does? You just need to emulate the same thing with `boost::mutex`.

Comment: I know about boost::mutex and i have used it for shared data. However, i dont know how can we use it for methods? can you help by providing an example code?

Comment: Depending on the specifics, you might even be able to get away with some atomics.

Comment: Lock at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578904/how-do-synchronized-static-methods-work-in-java

Comment: `synchronized` for protecting shared data as well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The following is equivalent to a Java `synchronized` method in C++. In fact, it is exactly equivalent, with the obvious exceptions that it is written in a different language and a different threading library.

```
class Thing {
  public:
    static std::string createUniqueId () {
        boost::unique_lock<boost::mutex> synchronized(mutex_);
        // ... generate a unique id here.
    }

  protected:
    static boost::mutex mutex_;
};
```

Note that the mutex is *protected*, not *private*, allowing you to use the same mutex (as you should) in subclasses.

Comment: Notice that the given method is `static`.

Comment: Totally. Thanks for the catch.

Answer (score 0):

Use a static (i.e. class) mutex.

Answer (score 0):

actually i do not understand what you said that "but I am not sure how to apply this to C++ class methods"

```
boost::mutex
```

you want to use, you must declare that. is not take effect now
you must use

```
`boost::mutex::scoped_lock `
```

to effect it
it can unlock automaticlly