# Please Explain How Java synchronized work with static method?

Tags: java, static, synchronized

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Java synchronized methods: lock on object or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620/java-synchronized-methods-lock-on-object-or-class)

Please Explain How Java synchronized work with static method ? Some one has said that it is done by its Class Object but they don't say how the lock is done with that.

Comment: Instead of locking on the instance, it locks on the object which epresents the class. Google for more details.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/578904/how-do-synchronized-static-methods-work-in-java

Answer (score 1):

You always synchronize on a monitor object. Every Java object can be used here.

With a synchronized block, you can specify that object directly.

```
synchronized (something){
}
```

With a synchronized method, it synchronizes on the object instance itself (on `this`), so it is identical to:

```
synchronized (this) {
}
```

With a synchronized static method, it synchronizes on the class object, just like "some one has said".

```
synchronized (ThisClass.class){
}
```

The mechanism is always the same: Only one thread can hold the lock at the same time, others have to wait.

Comment: No , I ment that static method and instance method. So how both method synchronized block when they access. Specially static method. What is the loked concept when it access.

Comment: `static synchronized void theMethod(){}` does the same thing as `static void theMethod(){ synchronized(ThisClass.class){} }`