# Object and instance are same things?

Tags: java, synchronization

While reading about synchronization, I read static synchronized method locked on class object and synchronized method locks on current instance of an object.
I have confusion what is class object and instance of an object? Don't object and instance are same things?

Comment: The class is like a recipe, an object instance is like a cake. You need the recipe to make a cake. You can make more than one cake. You need to synchronize on the recipe though, because otherwise you might add eggs when you should be frosting. Once the cake is made, you need to synchronize on it unless only one person is eating it. And that ends my cake metaphor. Because now I want cake.

Answer (score 2):

For every class loaded into JVM , an instance of class Class will be created.
for ex:
Student student = new Student()

when above line of code executed  class (Student) get loaded into JVM first bcz JVM needs template to create object .And based on template JVM creates  instance of Student in heap .Along with Student instance JVM creates instance of class Class in heap.This class instance all the information about STudent like number of constructors,methods,variables etc we use for reflection.

Now  all the instances (object) created will have a lock associated with then which comes into picture when executing synchronized methods or blocks (which can be static or instance) . if you are executing any static methods in synchronized context then lock of Class class (of STudent) will be acquired until its completion .

Comment: Dear spa , thank you for the answer , could you please provide me the source of the answer so that I can read this in depth.

Comment: Hi navneet u go through ''inside the java 2 virtual machine" by bill venners

Answer (score 1):

The operative word there is **class**. Every class has an instance of [`java.lang.Class`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/Class.html) that represents it in the current classloader.

Consider this simple example:

```
public class MyClass {
    public synchronized void instanceMethod() {
        // This method will synchronize on the instance of MyClass that called it
    }

    public static synchronized void staticMethod() {
        // This method will synchronize on  MyClass.class
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

I think whatever you are reading this from could have worded this in a better way.

The difference between synchronised instance methods and synchronised static methods is that the latter "locks" the class while the former locks the instance of that class  on which the synchronised method is called. See this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/578904/how-do-synchronized-static-methods-work-in-java) for more info.

Assuming the author knows what he/she is talking about, the word "class object" creates confusion, because classes themselves are not objects. Is he/she talking about instances of `Class<T>`? Probably not. The author should have just said "class".

As to what's the difference between "object" and "instance" outside of the context of synchronisation, they mean really the same thing - those things that you create by calling constructors (and string literals).

Personally, I think that the word "object" has a higher level abstraction. When I am talking at a low level of abstraction (talking about individual lines of code e.g. "I created an instance of `Foo` here by writing `new Foo()`"), I would use "instance". When I am talking about things on a higher level (like how the whole system works), I tend to use "object". But this might be just me. Other people might use them interchangeably.