# Java Synchronization inside Another Thread

Tags: java

I have a quick question about Java synchronization.

Please assume the following code:

```
public class Test {
    private String address;
    private int age;

    public synchronized setAddress(String a) {
        address = a;
    }

    public synchronized setAge(int a) {
        age = a;
    }

    public synchronized void start() {
          ...

          listener = new Thread(new Runnable(){
              public void run() {
                      ...
                  setAge(10);
                      ...

                  synchronized(Test.this) {
                      address = null;
                  }
              }
          }
    }
}
```

I am a little bit unsure about Java synchronization when synchronized method or synchronized block is called inside another thread.

Assume the thread running class Test as A, and
the listener thread B.

Then if I execute the code above, does it guarantee that synchronized method calls and synchronized block are synchronized with the A (the thread running Test class) ?

Thank you for reading.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No,

The synchronized methods are locking the `Test` **instance**, while the synchronized block is locking the `Test` **class object**.

See [Java synchronized static methods: lock on object or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620/java-synchronized-methods-lock-on-object-or-class) and [Java Synchronized Block for .class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056243/java-synchronized-block-for-class)

Comment: Sorry for my mistake. I just changed Test.class to Test.this. Does it still mean they are not synchronized?

Comment: @so-ju no, in that case they *are* synchronized, since they are locking the same object.

Comment: So, you are saying that synchronized blocks or synchronized methods called inside the listener thread are synchronized with such methods called outside of the listener thread?

Comment: Read this : http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/concurrency/

It will make everything much more clear.