# synchronized(this) vs synchronized(MyClass.class)

Tags: java, synchronization

> **Possible Duplicate:**
> [Java Synchronized Block for .class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056243/java-synchronized-block-for-class)

I was reading through an [article](http://javarevisited.blogspot.in/2011/04/synchronization-in-java-synchronized.html) on synchronization. I am confused on below points and need more clarification

1. For synchronization block. How

   ```
   synchronized (this) {
       // code
   }
   ```

   differs from

   ```
   synchronized (MyClass.class) {
       // code
   }
   ```
2. Synchronizing instance method means threads will have to get exclusive lock on the instance, while synchronizing static method means thread will have to acquire a lock on whole class(correct me if I am wrong). So if a class has three methods and one of them is static synchronized then if a thread acquires lock on that method then that means it will acquire lock on the whole class. So does that mean the other two will also get locked and no other method will be able to access those two methods as the whole class is having lock?

Answer (score 38, accepted):

`MyClass.class` and `this` are different things, they are different references to different objects.

`this` - is a reference to this particular instance of the class, and

`MyClass.class` - is a reference to the `MyClass` description object.

These synchronization blocks differ in that the first will synchronize all threads that deal concretely with **this** instance of `MyClass`, and the second one will synchronize **all** threads independently of which object on which method was called.

Answer (score 14):

The first example (acquiring lock on `this`) is meant to be used in instance methods, the second one (acquiring lock on `class` object) -- in `static` methods.

If one thread acquires lock on `MyClass.class`, other threads will have to wait to enter the synchronized block of a `static` method that this block is located in. Meanwhile, all of the threads will be able to acquire lock for a particular instance of this class and execute instance methods.

Comment: only static class vars will be locked with synchronize(MyClass.class)  right?

Comment: @tgkprog You don't synchronize variables themselves, you synchronize access to them (via methods). `MyClass.class` is just an object and it is possible (though I can't imagine real case when it would be needed) to synchronize instance methods on it too, but in general this paradigm is used with static methods.

Comment: hmm i thought synchronize(MyClass.class) locks up only static variables declared in the class. will have to look it up. So your saying if i had 1,000 instances of my class, each with 100 variables, they would all be locked?

Comment: `MyClass.class` is just an object, just like `this`. Answering your question, yes, if all of the methods acessing these variables are synchronized on the same object.

Comment: i did some rading, your right. you would use it with static vars but no reason why it can't be used for a global lock n non static block/ vars

Comment: Say, for a simple/naive implementation of an LRU cache with only the get(key) and put(key, value) methods, do you use `MyClass.class` to synchronize the threads? We only want one thread to enter the class and perform the get or put operation.