# puzzled when using synchronized lock

Tags: java, concurrency, java.util.concurrent, concurrent-programming

See below code, this puzzles me, in class DynamicPropertyFactory, it locks ConfigurationManager.class, as my understanding, the lock works only in the class or the instance itself. How to understand this?

```
public class *DynamicPropertyFactory*{
      public static *DynamicPropertyFactory* initWithConfigurationSource(AbstractConfiguration config) {
            synchronized (**ConfigurationManager.class**) {
                if (config == null) {
                    throw new NullPointerException("config is null");
                }
                if (ConfigurationManager.isConfigurationInstalled() && config != ConfigurationManager.instance) {
                    throw new IllegalStateException("ConfigurationManager is already initialized with configuration "
                            + ConfigurationManager.getConfigInstance());
                }
                if (config instanceof DynamicPropertySupport) {
                    return initWithConfigurationSource((DynamicPropertySupport) config);
                }
                return initWithConfigurationSource(new ConfigurationBackedDynamicPropertySupportImpl(config));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: why you locking `class` in first place?

Comment: "the lock works only in the class or the instance itself" It's unclear what you mean here.

Comment: Also note that `synchronized` does not "lock" anything. It *acquires* an exclusive lock on an object's monitor (in this case `ConfigurationManager.class`) preventing multiple synchronized methods or blocks that use the same lock to run at the same time.

Comment: You synchronize against the ConfigurationManager.class object. That does not mean all methods inside that class do so. only if they too use the synchronized keyword or acquire a lock on the class object.

Comment: A Class is a (singleton) object too. It might be that that class has synchronized methods, the above synchronisation wants to synchronize with them too. Quite ugly of course.

Comment: Your code is entirely equivalent to making the method itself synchronized. Do you understand that?

Answer (score 1):

> as my understanding, the lock works only in the class or the instance itself

This is wrong and unclear what you want to say.

lock can be taken on any reference which is not pointing to `null`.

```
synchronized (ConfigurationManager.class)
```

this line means that on `class` object lock is being taken.

Comment: sorry for my poor english. I do not understand why DynamicPropertyFactory class using synchronized  with another class, mostly, I write code like public class *DynamicPropertyFactory*{public static *DynamicPropertyFactory* initWithConfigurationSource(AbstractConfiguration config) {
            synchronized (this) {}}

Answer (score 0):

In this case lock on `ConfigurationManager.class` works like global monitor.

If you put the same lock in to `ConfigurationManager` **instance** then it 
will synchronize all threads, which deal each instance of `ConfigurationManager`.

Comment: But what does this to do with class DynamicPropertyFactory, it cannot be synchronized with threads on DynamicPropertyFactory class or its instance

Comment: Imagine that ConfigurationManager.class are static/constant/global monitor for prevent any async performance on its block.
Unfortunately my English skills also to poor. And i can't explain another way )

Answer (score 0):

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056243/java-synchronized-block-for-class) is highly relevant; remember that the target of your `synchronized(target)` is the thing that manages the mutual exclusivity of the code block. Only one thread can execute the code block at any given time, based on whether the monitor of the target is locked, but the target isn't necessarily always the same object.

Everywhere you refer to `ConfigurationManager.class` in your code should resolve to the same object, so it should work as a universal lock. However, using something like `synchronized(this)` combined with many instances would result in a lock per instance and some ability for that code to be run in parallel across those instances, just never in parallel on any single instance.

Locking on .class is considered bad practice and you should opt for something like `private static final Object lock = new Object();` instead, if you really must have a global lock.

Comment: Seems understanding something when reading your post,should read more times. Thanks.