# JAVA synchronized block not working in a multithreaded environment

Tags: java, multithreading, sockets, synchronization

I have the below code and trying to understand why the synchronization is not achieved here:

```
class Main {
    Thread t1 = new OpenServerSockets();
    t1.start();
}

public class OpenServerSockets extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run() {
        while(true){
            Thread t = new ClientResponder(clientSocket, dis, dos);
            t.start();
        }
    }

public class ClientResponder extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(this) {
            // some other static method call in another class.
        }
    }
}
```

The synchronized block gets called by multiple threads at the same time. Why is it so? Isn't synchronized block used this way not supposed to ensure mutual exclusion execution of code?

Comment: `this` is different for each Thread.  Use a static Object

Comment: you probably have more than one instance of `ClientResponder`, so `this` will vary

Comment: Ok, I got the point but what is a static object and how do we use one?

Comment: @Pankaj check posted the answer. An alternate approach is to pass lock object while creating the thread or pass ReentrantLock which provides the advanced features.

Comment: Okay, so what I understood is that when we use `synchronized(ClassName.class)` , here ClassName.class is treated as a static object?

Comment: @Pankaj Yes. I have updated the answer which uses `ReentrantLock`.

Answer (score 2):

I can see the lock is on `this`.

```
Thread t1 = new ClientResponder();
Thread t2 = new ClientResponder();
```

Now for `t1` and `t2` `this` is referring to a different objects. You need a class level lock.

```
public class ClientResponder extends Thread {
    @Override
    public void run(){
        synchronized(ClientResponder.class) {
            // some other static method call in another class.
        }
    }
}
```

The better approach would be to use `ReentrantLock`. It provides advanced features which `syncronized` doesn't provide

```
class ClientResponder extends Thread {

   public static final ReentrantLock lock = new ReentrantLock ();

    @Override
    public void run() {
        lock.lock ();
        // task.
        lock.unlock ();
    }
}
```

A quick read for the reference: [Java Synchronized Block for .class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2056243/java-synchronized-block-for-class)

Rentrant Lock: https://javarevisited.blogspot.com/2013/03/reentrantlock-example-in-java-synchronized-difference-vs-lock.html

Comment: Thanks @Govinda for the answer. Will be helpful if you can share some more insights for the Reentrant lock or a link to a good read. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

As has been covered in the comments, you're synchronizing on different objects, so there's no coordination between the threads.

Instead, you need to have the threads share an object that they synchronize on. You could create that object in `Main` or `OpenServerSockets` and then pass it into the constructor of `ClientResponder`, and then `ClientResponder` could synchronize on that object.

But there are other possible issues:

1. It's not clear why `OpenServerSockets` should be a `Thread`
2. It seems odd that `OpenServerSockets` **constantly** spawns new threads in a tight loop
3. You're wrapping your entire `ClientResponder` `run` method in a single `synchronized` block. That means that for the thread's entire useful life it's holding the lock. That seems unlikely to be what you need.
4. In general, it's best practice to implement `Runnable` rather than to extend `Thread`, and then pass an instance of the class implementing `Runnable` into `new Thread`.

Re #2: `ClientResponder`'s `run` should instead probably look something like this:

```
public void run(){
    while (this.running) {
        synchronized (this.objectToSynchronizeOn) {
            // Do one unit of work that requires synchronization
        }
    }
}
```

That way, each of the threads gets a chance to do something in-between the work done by other threads.

Comment: Thanks for the answer Crowder. I have posted an edited snippet of the code just to ask where I had doubts.

Comment: @Pankaj - Sure, of course, and that's good. A key thing when doing a [mcve], though, is to make sure it is representative of your actual code. If your actual code doesn't have the *entire* `run` method in the `synchronized` block, for instance, the MRE shouldn't either (even if it just has comments or something).

Comment: Thanks @Crowder, dint heard of the MRE concept before. It's a cool thing.