# Synchronized block equivalent to static synchronized method?

Tags: java

When you have a method such as the following:

```
public synchronized void addOne() {
    a++;
}
```

it is equivalent to the following: (correct me if I'm wrong)

```
public void addOne() {
    synchronized(this) {
        a++;
    }
}
```

But what is the equivalent to the following method?:

```
public static synchronized void addOne() {
    a++;
    // (in this case 'a' must be static)
}
```

**What is a synchronized block that acts the same as a static synchronized method?** I understand the static synchronized method is synchronized on the class and not the instance (since there is no instance), but what is the syntax for that?

Comment: possible duplicate of [Java synchronized methods: lock on object or class](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620/java-synchronized-methods-lock-on-object-or-class)

Comment: Eh, but that question doesn't have the code snippet that Quartermeister pointed out. I think this is distinct and good to have on hand.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

It is equivalent to locking on the class object.  You can get a reference to the class object by writing the class name followed by `.class`.  So, something like:

```
synchronized(YourClass.class) {
}
```

See the [Java Language Specification, Section 8.4.3.6 `synchronized` Methods](http://java.sun.com/docs/books/jls/second_edition/html/classes.doc.html#260369):

> A synchronized method acquires a lock
>   (§17.1) before it executes. For a
>   class (static) method, the lock
>   associated with the Class object for
>   the method's class is used. For an
>   instance method, the lock associated
>   with this (the object for which the
>   method was invoked) is used.

Comment: Yes, and thanks for referencing the JLS - always an interesting read! Here is an updated link on the Oracle domain: [JLS §8.4.3.6](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-8.html#jls-8.4.3.6).  It also provides a trivial example which illustrates that "the monitor associated with the Class object" is indeed the class itself.