# Class A has 2 synch methods in Java, Class B has two static synch methods, Are 2 threads allowed to access these two scenarios

Tags: java, synchronization, thread-safety

```
public class ThreadTest {
     public static synchronized void m2() {
         System.out.println("static sync m2");
         System.out.println("current"+Thread.currentThread());
         try { Thread.sleep(2000); }
         catch (InterruptedException ie) {}
     }

    public static void main(String[] args) throws InterruptedException {
        Thread t3 = new Thread() {
            public void run() {
                ThreadTest.m2();
            }
        };
        t3.start();
        t3.sleep(2000);
        Thread.sleep(500); // which thread are we sleeping here?
        System.out.println("t3.getState"+t3.getState());
    }
}
```

If we create another thread t1 and access ThreadTest.m2(); inside of this? yes this will be allowed, why this is static and it class level. But if we have non-static methods, then Thread 1 and 2 are not allowed to access the method

Comment: What do you mean by "allowed" or "not allowed" to access the method? Are you referring to whether or not the thread becomes blocked when trying to call m2()?

Answer (score 0):

Please check this out: [Java synchronized static methods: lock on object or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620/java-synchronized-methods-lock-on-object-or-class)

Regards.

Edit: in particular, this answer: [Java synchronized static methods: lock on object or class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620/java-synchronized-methods-lock-on-object-or-class/437821#437821)