# Synchronized method, when to use

Tags: java, synchronization

I need to create a class to wrap other classes and methods (3rd party) that are not "thread safe".
I actually want to create a single threaded class/method.

This should do it:

```
public class SomeClass {
    public static synchronized void performTask(int val) {
        //interesting non-thread safe code...
        ThisClass thisclass = new ThisClass();
        thisclass.dostuff();
        ThatClass thatclass = new ThatClass();
        thatclass.dootherstuff();
        HisClass hisclass = new HisClass();
        hisclass.notsure();
    }
```

1 static class with 1 static method which is synchronized.
So if multiple objects are using / calling this class. They will have to wait "in-line". Performance will suffer if heavy load.

```
public class MyClass {
    public void mytask() {
        //interesting code
        SomeClass.performTask(myval); // will wait if some other code block is in SomeClass.performTask?
    }
```

Comment: You might have to have a look at this
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/437620/java-synchronized-methods-lock-on-object-or-class

Comment: So if multiple objects are using/calling this class, they will wait "in-line" and performance may suffer if heavy load?

Comment: If your question is: "will this decrease performance on heavy load?" then the answer is "yes, absolutely"

Answer (score 0):

`Synchronization` is required in `multi-threaded` environment. When multiple thread can access your resource concurrently there you may required `synchronization` on resource access.